# Previously i have added color: red to my code, however i have deleted it, but it still shows on my web

Tags: php, css

[image]Previously i have added color red to my css code. However, i have deleted the code. But the red still remain on the web. What should i do? This is the html on my php file.

```
 echo "  <div class='toship-info'>
          <div class='toship-header'>Deliver to: </div>
          <div class='toship-content'>
          <div class='toship-att'>Name : </div>
          <div class='toship-data'>$ship_name</div>
          <div class='toship-att'>Address : </div>
          <div class='toship-data'>$ship_address</div>
          <div class='toship-att'>Contact No : </div>
          <div class='toship-data'>$ship_contact</div>
          <div class='toship-att'>Email : </div>
          <div class='toship-data'>$ship_email</div>
   <br><strong>*If there is any inquiries please contact our Apex Store at
   +6(04)-3901025. </strong></br>
    </div>
       </div>
            ";
```

This is my css file. How should i change it?

```
.toship-info{
width: 600px;
margin: auto;
 }

 .toship-header{
background: rgb(63,63,63);
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
padding-left: 15px;
}

.toship-content{
background: rgb(238,238,238);
height: 130px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.toship-att{
width: 100px;
text-align: left;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 3px;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toship-data{
width: 500px;
padding: 3px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12px;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toship-item{
width: 600px;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.toship-item-header{
background: rgb(63,63,63);
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
[![enter image description here][1]][1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to open in other browser, or if you are using any framework or cms then clear view cache.

Comment: This should be comment

Comment: I even put color: black; to make the word black

Comment: @ketan : I thought this should be the ans.

Comment: @rrd : I meant to open site with fresh cache, or clear current browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser probably cached the page. Try to clean your history/cache. How to do this depends on the browser you are using. For example, in Chrome you will go to History > History > Clear navigation data... > Image and files stored in cache. Also, as @rrd said in comments, in most browsers (Chrome included) Ctrl+R will reload the actual page and not the cached one.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-F5 will do the trick. It's in the browser cache. Ctrl-F5 will ask for a complete new request and hence avoid the cache.

Answer (score 0):

When i use the below code i don't see any red text

```
<style>
            .toship-info {
            width: 600px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .toship-header {
            background: rgb(63, 63, 63);
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 24px;
            line-height: 24px;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }

        .toship-content {
            background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
            height: 130px;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        .toship-att {
            width: 100px;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 3px;
            float: left;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .toship-data {
            width: 500px;
            padding: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 12px;
            float: left;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .toship-item {
            width: 600px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .toship-item-header {
            background: rgb(63, 63, 63);
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 24px;
            line-height: 24px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;

    </style>
</head>

<body>



    <div class='toship-info'> "
        <div class='toship-header'>Deliver to: </div>
        <div class='toship-content'>
            <div class='toship-att'>Name : </div>
            <div class='toship-data'>$ship_name</div>
            <div class='toship-att'>Address : </div>
            <div class='toship-data'>$ship_address</div>
            <div class='toship-att'>Contact No : </div>
            <div class='toship-data'>$ship_contact</div>
            <div class='toship-att'>Email : </div>
            <div class='toship-data'>$ship_email</div>
            <br>
            <strong>*If there is any inquiries please contact our Apex Store at
   +6(04)-3901025. </strong>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Please make sure you markup your HTML properly..

 was incorrectly marked up